# How do I implement an 'update' function?

Tags: c#, winforms, function, methods

I was doing some exercises for school and ended up writing a piece of code for a listbox as shown below. Now notice how 3 lines of code always return in 3 different privates;

```
int numberOfItems = lstItems.Items.Count;
string y = numberOfItems.ToString();
txtAantal.Text = y;
```

I want to place them in some kind of function or method which I could simply call in each of the privates where this code is needed but I don't know how to do this, could anyone please give me a hand with this?

```
namespace IList
{
public partial class frmAddItem : Form
{
    public frmAddItem()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string newItem = txtItem.Text;
        lstItems.Items.Add(newItem);
        int numberOfItems = lstItems.Items.Count;
        string y = numberOfItems.ToString();
        txtAantal.Text = y;
        txtItem.Text = "";
    }

    private void lstItems_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int Selected = lstItems.SelectedIndex;
        Selected += 1;
        string x = Selected.ToString();
        txtSelected.Text = x;
    }

    private void btnRemoveAt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int Location = int.Parse(txtRemoveAt.Text);
        Location -= 1;
        lstItems.Items.RemoveAt(Location);
        int numberOfItems = lstItems.Items.Count;
        string y = numberOfItems.ToString();
        txtAantal.Text = y;
    }

    private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lstItems.Items.Clear();
        int numberOfItems = lstItems.Items.Count;
        string y = numberOfItems.ToString();
        txtAantal.Text = y;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Not clear what you want tpo achieve

Answer (score 1):

Actually, these three lines of code can be turned into a one liner, which would eliminate the need to extract them to an independent method:

```
textAantal.Text = lstBox.Items.Count.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a single private method like below.

```
 private void myActionMethod(string action)
    {

      switch (action)
      {
        case "btnAdd_Click"
              string newItem = txtItem.Text;
              lstItems.Items.Add(newItem);
              int numberOfItems = lstItems.Items.Count;
              string y = numberOfItems.ToString();
              txtAantal.Text = y;
              txtItem.Text = "";
             break;

       case "lstItems_SelectedIndexChanged"
            int Selected = lstItems.SelectedIndex;
            Selected += 1;
            string x = Selected.ToString();
            txtSelected.Text = x;
            break;

      case "btnClear_Click"
            int Location = int.Parse(txtRemoveAt.Text);
            Location -= 1;
            lstItems.Items.RemoveAt(Location);
            int numberOfItems = lstItems.Items.Count;
            string y = numberOfItems.ToString();
            txtAantal.Text = y;
            break;
    case "btnRemoveAt_Click"
          int Location = int.Parse(txtRemoveAt.Text);
          Location -= 1;
          lstItems.Items.RemoveAt(Location);
          int numberOfItems = lstItems.Items.Count;
          string y = numberOfItems.ToString();
          txtAantal.Text = y;
          break;
      }
    }
```

Call your method in each event

```
    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      myActionMethod("btnAdd_Click");
    }
    private void lstItems_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       this. myActionMethod("lstItems_SelectedIndexChanged");
    }

   private void btnRemoveAt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this. myActionMethod("btnRemoveAt_Click");
    }
   private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       this. myActionMethod("btnClear_Click");
   }
```

You can name myActionMethod into any name MyUpdateMethod or whatever. I hope this helps.

Comment: How is this approach better? You create a bloated `switch` statement and relay on string method names to execute your code?

Comment: Its a matter of choice Yuval. His question asked "I want to place them in some kind of function or method" and i am sure he has his reason. I am just trying to give him what he wants. Hope it helps .